# Accidently Deleted GL folder located at /usr/include/GL

Tags: linux, opengl

[I am working on Fedora 19 x64]

This sounds silly but I intended to remove the GL folder located at /usr/local/include. But I accidently removed the GL folder located at /usr/include.

So I have kind of lost gl.h, glu.h and many other header file.

Is there any way to fix this.

Comment: what about reinstall the (dev-)package?

Comment: I am kind of noob here please guide me further. how to reinstall (dev-)package ? I mean what command

Comment: Try `sudo yum reinstall mesa-common-dev`

Comment: okay I got an error :
No Match for argument: mesa-common-dev
Error: Nothing to do

Comment: No it's `sudo yum reinstall mesa-libGL-devel` on fedora, srry I'm on debian

Comment: okay trying : Its working its working, I got gl.h but still not able to get glu.h. 
Oh update: I searched for    yum search mesa  and eventually found `mesa-libGLU-devel.x86_64`

Comment: Then do additonally `sudo yum reinstall mesa-libGLU-devel`. After this you should be fine again. have answered this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reinstall the following packages:

```
sudo yum reinstall mesa-libGL-devel
sudo yum reinstall mesa-libGLU-devel
```